# mysql join four tables and get records older than 1 month

Tags: mysql

I want to join four tables and get records older than 30 days. I think I'm doing fine but not in the date older than 30 days.

it returns empty results.
my query:

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
       a.memberid, 
       c.id,
       d.memberid AS uid,
       d.datecreated 
FROM   `tbl_members` c 
       LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
              ON c.`id` = b.`accountid` 
       LEFT JOIN `table2` a 
              ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
       LEFT JOIN `table3` d 
              ON a.`id` = d.`memberid`
WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
       AND a.memberid IS NULL 
       AND b.accountid IS NULL 
       AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= d.datecreated
ORDER  BY uid
```

records:

```
tbl_members
---------------------------
id | username | is_active |
 1 |   user1  |     1     |
---------------------------
table1
------------------------------
id | accountid | datecreated |
   |           |             |
------------------------------
table2
------------------------------
id | memberid  | datecreated |
   |           |             |
------------------------------
table3
----------------------------------------
id | memberid  |      datecreated      |
 1 |     1     | 2018-06-21 00:12:51   |
----------------------------------------
```

when I remove this line:

```
AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= d.datecreated
```

I'm getting the right results.

EDIT:
I'm getting the right results now by using this query:

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
       a.memberid, 
       d.memberid, 
       c.memberid AS uid, 
       d.datecreated 
FROM   `tbl_members` c 
       LEFT JOIN `tbl_bonus_direct` b 
              ON c.`memberid` = b.`accountid` 
       LEFT JOIN `tbl_wallet_cash` a 
              ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
       LEFT JOIN `tbl_members_accounts` d 
              ON c.`memberid` = d.`memberid`
WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
       AND a.memberid IS NULL 
       AND b.accountid IS NULL 
       AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= date(d.datecreated)
ORDER  BY uid
```

BUT I want to distinct the memberid in table3

Comment: You need `>=` in your comparison, but without seeing sample data, can't say if this is the only reason you are getting empty results.

Comment: when I remove this line:

AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= d.datecreated
I'm getting the right results.

Comment: but i tried this on a single table and getting the right results.
SELECT * FROM `table3` WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= datecreated

Comment: The DATE_SUB(...) gives you a default time of `00:00:00` so the comparison will be true.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I would also change the date of your test data to an earlier one. Most of the answers below will 'work' today because 2018-06-21 is exactly 30 days ago.

Comment: Your table structure does not match with your query. `tbl_members` doesn't have a `memberid` column. Impossible to reproduce.

Comment: thank you it's accurate now, the only thing is i want to distinct the memberid in table3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 1st mistake area

```
`tbl_members` c 
       LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
              ON c.`memberid` = b.`accountid`
```

here in table in `tbl_members` no column name is memberid 
2nd mistake

```
LEFT JOIN `table3` d 
              ON a.`memberid` = d.`memberid`
```

`table3` join will be happened with table `tbl_members`

now i'm going to correct your query and below is that

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
           a.memberid, 
           c.username,
           d.memberid AS uid,
           d.datecreated 
    FROM   `tbl_members` c 
           LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
                  ON c.`id` = b.`accountid` 
           LEFT JOIN `table2` a 
                  ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
           LEFT JOIN `table3` d 
                  ON c.`id` = d.`memberid`
    WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
           AND a.memberid IS NULL 
           AND b.accountid IS NULL 
           AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date(d.datecreated)
    ORDER  BY uid
```

I think you want something like this as you said you need distinct memberid

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
               a.memberid, 
               c.username,
               d.memberid AS uid,
               d.datecreated 
        FROM   `tbl_members` c 
               LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
                      ON c.`id` = b.`accountid` 
               LEFT JOIN `table2` a 
                      ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
               LEFT JOIN               
               (select distinct memberid, datecreated  from `table3` ) as  d 
                      ON c.`id` = d.`memberid`
        WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
               AND a.memberid IS NULL 
               AND b.accountid IS NULL 
               AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= date(d.datecreated)
        ORDER  BY uid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1aec8d/4

Comment: thank you it's accurate now, the only thing is i want to distinct the memberid in table3

Comment: in that case 1st distinct data from table3 then add it as sub-query to join with others table

Comment: can you guide me with that?

Comment: if you share data then it will be easy to guide you .

Comment: SELECT b.accountid, 
       a.memberid, 
       d.memberid, 
       c.memberid AS uid, 
       d.datecreated 
FROM   `tbl_members` c 
       LEFT JOIN `tbl_bonus_direct` b 
              ON c.`memberid` = b.`accountid` 
       LEFT JOIN `tbl_wallet_cash` a 
              ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
       LEFT JOIN `tbl_members_accounts` d 
              ON c.`memberid` = d.`memberid`
WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
       AND a.memberid IS NULL 
       AND b.accountid IS NULL 
       AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= date(d.datecreated)
ORDER  BY uid 


that query

Comment: i want that with distinct in table3

Comment: @guessguesshoo i have given another version  of query i think you want something like that

Comment: @guessguesshoo does it helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176471/discussion-between-guessguess-hoo-and-zaynul-abadin-tuhin).

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator is wrong. You are creating a date in the past using `DATE_SUB` but then only selecting records that are created after this date.

Change:

```
AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) <= d.datecreated
```

to:

```
AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= DATE(d.datecreated)
```

Adding the DATE() to the comparison should remove the issue you identified in your comments. The default time for DATE_SUB() is `00:00:00` and the comparison will take time of day into account. DATE() removes the time and so the comparison will only be on date.

So, your query becomes:

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
       a.memberid, 
       c.memberid,
       d.memberid AS uid,
       d.datecreated 
FROM   `tbl_members` c 
       LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
              ON c.`memberid` = b.`accountid` 
       LEFT JOIN `table2` a 
              ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
       LEFT JOIN `table3` d 
              ON a.`memberid` = d.`memberid`
WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
       AND a.memberid IS NULL 
       AND b.accountid IS NULL 
       AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= DATE(d.datecreated)
ORDER  BY uid
```

Comment: d is an inner join. Just sayin'